# What does "command" mean?

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, command

I dont understand what does this programme does :

```
if command -v apt-get > /dev/null; then
dpkg-query -W -f='...'
```

i dont understand how the command : "command" works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `man bash` or `help command` in bash for help:

> Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing  shell function lookup, ...

The `if` checks whether there is a command `apt-get`; if there is a function `apt-get`, it's ignored.

Comment: And, I think, if there is an alias, it is ignored as well. At least the man-page says: **Only** builtin commands or commands found in the PATH  are  executed.

Comment: From my testing it seems `command -v` doesn't ignore aliases, but in a script it's probably irrelevant, as non-interactive scripts usually don't `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Comment: The `-v` does not make sense for such a test. I just tested:  `command xxx` (without -v), and this indeed ignores an alias named `xxx` (bash version 4.4.12). I think it is worth mentioning aliases, because I found from discussions here that people for some reason seem to like them, and we don't know whether the OP is in an interactive context (the code displayed could be part of an interactively used shell function), or is non-interactive, but has alias expansion turned on.

Comment: The code in the question has `command -v`.

Comment: Indeed! Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to do things in the shell.

1. The default is to execute shell [builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).
2. Next commands (binaries, scripts, etc; basically something external to the shell) are looked up in the directories listed in the [`PATH` variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Variables.html).
3. This is followed by aliases. These are reusable abbreviations to commands, you can think of them as a way to save typing.  They are usually defined in the shell's rc files.  For example I have this defined in my `~/.bashrc`: `alias lt='ls --color=tty -lhtr'`; it lets me type only `lt` to get a reverse sorted list of files (newest at the bottom).
4. More complex commands can be grouped into shell functions.

The `command` command is a shell builtin that allows you to bypass any functions that might also match a binary in your `PATH`, or any aliases.  Say I use `rsync` frequently between specific hosts, so I wrote a function called `rsync` that includes the destination with all the options, allowing me to type less.  However if I want to run `rsync` with a different destination, I could use `command rsync <other rsync options>` to bypass the function definition.  Note that aliases are *not* bypassed; this is relevant if you are using `command` interactively.  You can find the documentation in the builtin page linked above, or by typing `help command`